# once ubuntu is installed do i always nee to use USB key?

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, usb

I have been going crazy for the past two days, trying to install UBUNTU 16.04 lts. 
First some backround info about what i did and what devices i am using:

I know very little about computers and have followed directions and read up on people with similar problems here on ask ubuntu, and well,  finally managed to install! Here's how:  I created a startup USB with the UBUNTU ISO file on it, whch i did from a computer with an ubuntu OS, so i used the STARTUP DISK CREATOR application. 
MY computer is a DELL LATTITUDE E7440, and HAD windows 7 enterprise on it until the windows session expired and i was using the computer wth a non genuine version of windows 7...SO  decided to install LINUX.

I succeeded in installing ubuntu a first time, choosing to overwrite all disks, as i plan to just get rid of windows (which is expired anyway) and simply use ubuntu as an OS. As i told you i did this by using a USB key with ISO file on it. When i finished the installation ubuntu had me choose between exploring ubuntu or finalizing the installation by restarting the computer. I restarted and....stupidly (maybe i ddn't wait long enough?) removed the usb key as soon as the screen went black and when the computer restarted... it restarted WINDOWS! (Or should  say, the expired version of windows 7...) I tried rebooting again from the USB key but a black screen appeared (which i no longer knew if it was wndows or ubuntu...) with lots of wrting (i'm sorry i really don't know the slightest thing about computers!) with at the end this kind of error:

kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,2)

So at this point i started everything over again, and re-created a bootable USB drive using STARTUP DISK CREATOR and was able to reinstall UBUNTU on my dell. 
I did everything the same, except this time after completing installation i left the usb key in the drive and haven't taken it out yet... whch is why i'm writing to you all... i'm actually worried if i DO withdraw the USB key, i will have to start all over again... and the ubuntu installing wll just disappear and windows will come back. (I don't understand how this is possible if i completed installation in which i chose to overwrite all existing disks and OS!)

Here is my queston, to which i really need an answer because i have searched all over the web, and found nothing:

Can i take out the USB key?????!! Or does the USB key allow me to use UBUNTU? If so, wouldn't that mean it is a LIVE version of ubuntu? Whereas i am looking for using it as my all-time OS...And durng installation i never had to choose between live ubuntu or a more permanent one.

Could this could have happened because the computer i used to download ubuntu and create a startup disk has an older version of ubuntu than the one i installed (16.04 lts) ??

If it is any use, i am NOT interested in a dual boot... i JUST want to use linux!

I thank you for your time, this has been a very detailed message, but i felt like i should be clear on everything i did !

Thank you very much for any help you can give me!

Pajarito

---

it seems like i am talkng by myself here but no worres, i believe we live in diifferent tiime zones.

I just wanted to say that i have finally succeeded in getting rid of windows.. to do so i opened up disks on my ubuntu desktop (for i have TWO disks) . And since onewas 92 % full...i guessed that was where windows was, full f viruses and malware. So i just erased the drive from the disks area, and voilà!

No more windows when i boot the computer..; BUUUT it still doesn't directly boot into ubuntu, i get :" Invalid partition table " I checked this out and read that maybe boot repair would be the solution.... is this true?

thanks everyone for reading and suport :)

Comment: First things first, if you want a dual boot, do not select the "install alongside¨ and considering you just tried to install why not do it again, correctly?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes, it is. I meant "if you **don't** want a dual boot, do no select install alongside"... The answer posted meanwhile presents the essentials for doing what the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: thank you so much for your quick reply.
I don't understand what you mean when you say select "try ubuntu" after boot in the USB media.... i never had anything to selct really. I just get a message saying "missing parameter in configuration file. Keyword :path gfxboot.c32 not a COM32R image
boot: i found out that if i hit TAB and then type in live, can proceed to the desktop and ubuntu starts up. I then realised after wrting my first message that instead of typing "live" i had to type "live-install", whch brought me to the desktop and the installation window was already open, not an icon on the

Comment: This is weird. Do you mean that, when you boot with the live USB, you don't get the graphical interface?. If it is, you should create a live USB using [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/). Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which method do you use to install, legacy boot, or UEFI?. If you formatted the disk, how is possible that Windows starts again? Add detailed information in What you are doing, so we can offer a better solution to your problem. Also, visit the link I posted in the previous answer, there are images referring to I'm talking about. Best regards.

Comment: Yes, when i boot the live USB i dont get a graphical interface, just  "missing parameter in configuration file. Keyword :path gfxboot.c32 not a COM32R image boot:" And then for a graphical interface to appear, i have to type in "ive-install" or else the message just keeps repeating itself. 
And i HAVE looked at the link you sent me, it's the one i used to install, but i never got the choice of "try ubuntu VS install ubuntu"
I just get the error code i mentioned earlier. 
At first i used a MAC to create the flash drive using Unetbootin, and when i tried to install it was the same thing.

Comment: So i created a flash drive using a frend's computer who has ubuntu, the 14.04 version, and used the startup disk creator app. 
When i used unetbootin there was an error uploading the SO on the flash drive, and i had to go and add three files to the USB root... but i never found out how, and read here on ubuntu help that there is a bug wth unetbootin...so i made another flash drive with ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You ask me the method i used to install,  i don't understand... all i did was create flash USB and when i order my PC to boot with USB (f12) all that happens is the error page  metoned and i'm eventually able to open up ubuntu, even completed installation but if i wthdraw USB, windows comes back.

Comment: and the only time ii format any dsk is during UBUNTU installaton, which iis on the key. So maybe i need to download another version of ubuntu? Or create another flash drive?
But like i said my only options are a MAC or this computer that has 14.04 ubuntu on it to create a flash drive and unetbootin on mac didn't work out for me...

Comment: ok hey again, here's the latest update:
I downloaded unetbootin and made yet another flash key. 
This time when i booted up the computer a blue screen appeared (written unetbootin on top) and there were more than one options: try ubuntu or install ubuntu ... so i obvously chose to install ubuntu. I did everything as usual, chose to erase disk and only put ubuntu, and guess what? i did what you sad and shut down, withdrew usb. When i rebooted. Windows again. 

i'm going nuts

Comment: hello, again... I'm sorry but i keep having new questions and updates. I installed YET again ubuntu after my last message and when i was done i restarted wth the key and everything restarted as normal. I checked in "about this computer" and it says that  only have about 4 GB of disk space.... which seems VERY little for a freshly wiped out computer (since apparently, windows is supposed to be erased). SO there are two possibilities (that i thought of) either there is very little space because windows is still there, or the space mentioned is that of the USB drive... which would mean ubuntu

Comment: installed fully on USB key and NOT my computer....

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/667511)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your USB device from the PC. To do it in the safe way:

1. Select "Try Ubuntu" after boot in the USB media.
2. Open or install gParted. (Optional)
3. Format the partitions, or create a new partition table. (msdos for BIOS mode, or gpt, for UEFI mode). (Optional)
4. Launch the Ubuntu installer, located in the desktop (as I remember).
5. Select the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option.
6. Wait until the install finishes.
7. When done, close the install program, and turn off the PC, by going to the session buttons at the top right corner, at the gear icon. Then press "Shut down".
8. Remove your USB media.
9. Turn on the PC again.
10. Wait for the boot process to complete, it could take a while the first time.

For more information look at [Install Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)